# Is there a way to modify the default indents and tabs in OSX's Text Edit app?

Tags: macos, textedit

Tab stops and indents can be modified on an individual document basis by clicking/dragging within the ruler area, but this must be done for every file.

Is there a way to modify the default indents and tab stops?

Comment: This has been answered in https://superuser.com/questions/697207/change-tab-spacing-in-textedit-on-os-x